# Install Ghostscript on OS X 10.9 using DMG file

Tags: macos, install, dmg

I want to install Ghostscript on my OS X 10.9 using a valid DMG file, where can i find it?

Answer (score 10):

The program homebrew worked for me on Mac OS10.9.5:

Type the following in the command line:

```
brew install ghostscript
```

Answer (score 5):

You can find the package (`.pkg` installable with the *Installer* built-in utility) on the [site of Richard Koch](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/).

Comment: This package does not contain "libgs.dylib"

Comment: Best solution. Updated now!

Answer (score 0):

I found this link and hope it assists you.

http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Download

Kind regards,

Comment: Please expand your answer — link-only answers can be invalidated if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Think Marie-Brigitte Souci and her link-only answer pointing to http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Download shows where to find the libgs.dylib file...